# Failed to install pysam 0.13

Tags: python, c, gcc, pip, pysam

I keep on failing to install pysam 0.13 on macOS High Sierra. 
To sum up my two errors:

```
htslib/htslib/hts.h:142:9: error: missing ',' between enumerators
    json HTS_DEPRECATED_ENUM("Use htsExactFormat 'htsget' instead") = htsget,
        ^
        ,  htslib/htslib/hts.h:142:29: error: expected '= constant-expression' or end of
      enumerator definition
    json HTS_DEPRECATED_ENUM("Use htsExactFormat 'htsget' instead") = htsget,
                        ^
```

2 errors generated.

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I solved it So the problem was the htslib. Solved with:

```
export HTSLIB_LIBRARY_DIR=/usr/local/lib
export HTSLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/include
pip install pysam
```

The problem was the contradictory htslib libraries in the same directories.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes software needs modifications (patches) to work on a specific operating system. Or it won't build when you have older header files installed. Or it needs a different compiler.

Since your system (macOS) lacks a good native package management, I would suggest that you use a Python distribution that has its own package manager, like e.g. [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

Such distributions have a lot of pre-compiled packages (like pysam) available. They can save you a lot of time.